# Is it possible to use ASP.NET Dynamic Data and SubSonic 3?

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3, dynamic-data

Is it possible to use ASP.NET Dynamic Data with SubSonic 3 in-place of Linq to SQL classes or the Entity Framework? MetaModel.RegisterContext() throws an exception if you use the context class that SubSonic generates. I thought I remembered coming across a SubSonic/Dynamic Data example back before SubSonic 3 was released but I can't find it now. Has anyone been able to get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

I just got Subsonic 3.0.0.4 ActiveRecord working last night in Visual Studio 2010 with my SQLite database after a little bit of work and I've tried to document the steps taken here for your benefit.

Start by adding a **New Item -> WCF Data Service** to the project you're using to host your webapp/webservices then modify it similar to my PinsDataService.svc.cs below:

```
public class PinsDataService : DataService<PINS.Lib.dbPINSDB>
{
    // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
        config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
    }
}
```

At this point your Dynamic Data Service would probably be working if you matched all the database naming conventions perfectly but I didn't have that kind of luck. In my **ActiveRecord.tt** template I had to prepend the following two lines before the public partial class declarations:

```
[DataServiceKey("<#=tbl.PrimaryKey #>")]
[IgnoreProperties("Columns")]
public partial class <#=tbl.ClassName#>: IActiveRecord {
```

I then added references to **System.Data** and **System.Data.Services.Client** followed by the inclusion of using statements for **using System.Data.Services** and **using System.Data.Services.Common** at the top of the **ActiveRecord.tt** template.

The next step was to use the IUpdateable partial class implementation from this blog post http://blogs.msdn.com/aconrad/archive/2008/12/05/developing-an-astoria-data-provider-for-subsonic.aspx and change the `public partial class dbPINSDB : IUpdatable` to match my subsonic DatabaseName declared in **Settings.ttinclude**

Then to consume the data in a separate client app/library I started by adding a 'Service Reference' named PinsDataService to the PinsDataService.svc from my client app and went to town:

```
PinsDataService.dbPINSDB PinsDb = 
 new PinsDataService.dbPINSDB(new Uri("http://localhost:1918/PinsDataService.svc/"));
PinsDataService.Alarm activeAlarm = 
   PinsDb.Alarms.Where(i => i.ID == myAA.Alarm_ID).Take(1).ElementAt(0);
```

Note how I'm doing a Where query that returns only 1 object but I threw in the Take(1) and then ElementAt(0) because I kept getting errors when I tried to use SingleOrDefault() or First()

Hope this helps--also, I'm already aware that dbPINSDB is a ***really*** bad name for my Subsonic Database ;)